# Tomcat Issues on Session Attribute on Tomcat 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, session-variables

i'm triyng to figure out this problem. I have a java web application, running finely on localhost. When i deploy the app on Tomcat (SSL enabled), when i login, i lose every session attribute.

The request are sent by useing : request.getRequestDispatcher("/somepath").forward(request, response);

Thanks in advance

G

Answer (score 0):

When switching from https to HTTP you will lose your session.. 
It really depends on your logic.. But my simple suggestion is after the user is logged in just keep the https..

When the user is logged out and pages of user logout which does not require https just use HTTP.

Here is some info regarding those things:

```
How would secure implementations look like and where can one expect problems?
```

These rules are intended to provide SSL protection, that is protection against an opponent that can intercept and alter packets.
Subcomponents

```
You probably into mixed mode in some scenarios
```

If, in an HTTPS page, you load any script, or CSS resource in plain HTTP, that nullifies the SSL benefit (not just reduce).

As a rule, in an HTTPS page, load every subcomponent (frames, scripts, styles, images) over HTTPS, from trustworthy hosts.
Cookies

A particularly unfortunate mistake is to forget to make all cookies "secure". If you forget to mark all security relevant cookies with this attribute, it nullifies the SSL security. (Obviously, a login/session cookie is security-sensitive.)

As you want your website to be entirely over HTTPS, mark all cookies "secure".

One problem is that even "secure" cookies can be replaced by cookies HTTP non-secure cookies! What makes it even worse is that the browser will not even tell you if the cookie came from HTTP or HTTPS!

You can assume that a secure cookie cannot be read by an opponent. But you cannot assume that a cookie sent by a browser over HTTPS is the secure cookie you sent previously.
Whole site SSL protection

By providing content over HTTPS not just for some "sensitive" pages, but for the whole site, you will train users to only use your site over HTTPS which is quite good for security.

In order for users to be able to enter an HTTP URL, you will certainly do an HTTP redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, so that the only non-encrypted HTTP traffic is an HTTP redirect (in the usual, no attack, case).

The problem here is that if users get used to typing the HTTP URL, and they might fail to check every time that they are properly redirected to the corresponding HTTPS site: an attacker that can intercept and modify packets can alter the HTTP request to redirect to another misleading HTTPS site, or just assume that the user doesn't usually detect the HTTP/HTTPS difference: this is a good reason to use HSTS.
Other website security principles

The SSL cryptographic protection is an essential part of website security, especially to protect the secrecy of passwords. But it isn't the end of the security requirements that are specific to websites.

Just as a reminder, some other essential security principles:
Safe handling of untrusted data

When taking user input and outputting it in web page, you must apply proper escaping to avoid XSS vulnerabilities. For this, you must understand that different parts of the HTML page have different syntax (normal HTML, attribute value, URL have completely different syntaxes) and thus need different escaping.

As in any other program taking external untrusted input, you must properly validate every input, and store and output it in a way that does not misbehave if an unusual character is present (see: SQL injection).
Verification of authorisation on the web

You cannot only rely on cookies (or HTTP authentication) to validate that a specific order from an HTTP client is authorised: doing so would expose your website to a CSS attack from another website if the user browses both websites in the same browser.
My view of secure design

The problem with website security is often caused either by not understanding the different specific requirements of these web protocols or by securing all but one "entry point".

Before you even to design a "secure" website, you should understand all these requirements; then you should apply them in a systematic way. Your design should be simple, regular, understandable, and easy to audit.

The best style is one where you just cannot forget to apply to escape text that is going to be interpreted as HTML/HTML attribute/SQL/SQL "regexp"/shell commands/shell regexp. The best approach, when possible, is to prevent variable data that is not intended to be interpreted as HTML/HTML attribute/SQL/SQL "wildcard expr"/shell commands/shell regexp to appear in such context that it requires escaping: avoiding need to escape is safer because you cannot forget to escape things.

I know that I am drifting off topic here... so I will stop now. I just wanted to it clear that HTTP security doesn't stop at "100 % over SSL".

Comment: I found out by checking the session id, that every time that the request.getRequestDispatcher is invoked, a new session is created.. So i can't really figure out what is wrong..

Comment: Are you using Spring or some other framework? If you always be on https only 1 session will be created, It can create 2 in case you are moving to http and then redirect to https again.. So the session will be gone and new session will be created

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is too late. But this might help someone else.

The following is an excerpt from Java Servlet Specification 3.0 -> Session -> Session Scope:

> HttpSession objects must be scoped at the application (or servlet
>   context) level.  The underlying mechanism, such as the cookie used to
>   establish the session, can be  the same for different contexts, but
>   the object referenced, including the  attributes in that object, must
>   never be shared between contexts by the container.
>
> To illustrate this requirement with an example:
>
> **if a servlet uses the
>       RequestDispatcher to call a servlet in another Web application, any sessions
>       created for and visible to the servlet being called must be different from those visible
>       to the calling servlet**

So in essence, whenever the Servlet Context changes, so do the session information. And using RequestDispatcher changes the Servlet Context, thus you lose all the session information.